# Use DecimalFormat to get varying amount of decimal places

Tags: java, string, decimalformat

So I want to use the Decimal Format class to round numbers:

```
double value = 10.555;

DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.##");

System.out.println(fmt.format(value));
```

Here, the variable `value` would be rounded to 2 decimal places, because there are two `#`s. However, I want to round `value` to an unknown amount of decimal places, indicated by a separate integer called `numPlaces`. Is there a way I could accomplish this by using the Decimal Formatter?

e.g. If `numPlaces = 3` and `value = 10.555`, `value` needs to be rounded to 3 decimal places

Comment: Are you committed to using `DecimalFormat`?  Because it's much easier if you use `Formatter` instead.

Comment: Why would you unaccept my answer and accept his? He copied my answer after I posted mine...

Comment: ? You edited your answer

Comment: @RealMadrid_CF I just edited my answer to make it specifically what you preferred. However, I posted my answer 5 minutes before he posted his and then he copied what I wrote. He even used the same example number `5`. You already accepted mine, so I don't see why you would unaccept it. Mine's more well-written anyways and was first.

Comment: Your first post was not the same as Don's. You saw that I marked his answer with a check, so you changed your answer to match his. Look at your edit history.

Comment: Ok if it makes you happy then I will mark your answer as correct...

Comment: @RealMadrid_CF Thank you. And no, his answer is the same as mine. I added in the last part afterwards, but he copied my way of solving the problems (using a for loop to add `#`s). The only difference between his answer and mine originally was he took my code out of the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a method to generate a certain number of `#` to a string, like so:

```
public static String generateNumberSigns(int n) {

    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s += "#";
    }
    return s;
}
```

And then use that method to generate a string to pass to the `DecimalFormat` class:

```
double value = 1234.567890;
int numPlaces = 5;

String numberSigns = generateNumberSigns(numPlaces);
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0." + numberSigns);

System.out.println(fmt.format(value));
```

---

OR simply do it all at once without a method:

```
double value = 1234.567890;
int numPlaces = 5;

String numberSigns = "";
for (int i = 0; i < numPlaces; i++) {
    numberSigns += "#";
}

DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0." + numberSigns);

System.out.println(fmt.format(value));
```

Comment: Is it possible that I just add the `DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0." + numberSigns);`, and not have to add the String method?

Comment: @RealMadrid_CF: Sure it is. You can move the code from the method into wherever you are using the `DecimalFormat`. The method is just a way of generating a certain number of `#`, but you can do it another way if you wanted. However, a method is good practise and it can be reused in multiple parts of code, classes, etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need the DecimalFormat for any other purpose, a simpler solution is to use `String.format` or `PrintStream.format` and generate the format string in a similar manner to Mike Yaworski's solution.

```
int precision = 4; // example
String formatString = "%." + precision + "f";
double value = 7.45834975; // example
System.out.format(formatString, value); // output = 7.4583
```

Comment: You saved my day, Thank you, before this was using RoundingMode.CEILING in kotlin and decimalFormat which was working good but sometimes it returns ex: 7123,12 and i want 7123.12 by using this i got the solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
double value = 10.5555123412341;
int numPlaces = 5;
String format = "0.";

for (int i = 0; i < numPlaces; i++){
    format+="#";
}
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat(format);

System.out.println(fmt.format(value));
```

Comment: Whatever the case is, you obviously read mine before posting yours (you used the same number of decimal places as me). I don't think you directly copied me; all I was trying to get across was that I posted first and with a more full solution. He was claiming I copied you, so I turned that around. I've upvoted your answer now that this is solved. I've also taken out the message to me in your post. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: actually, I didn't had the chance to read yours. right after posting, stack overflow said someone posted a minute before me. But I still posted. And since the number in the example is mostly composed of 5's, I decided to make the decimal places 5, also.

Answer (score -2):

If you're not absolutely bound to use `DecimalFormat,` you could use `BigDecimal.round()` for this in conjunction with `MathContext` of the precision that you want, then just `BigDecimal.toString().`