# How to set formatter as variable in Java?

Tags: java, android, format

I want to format double variabled in Java depending on a number stored in another variable double "i". Let's say if i=3, then I want to format

```
decimals_text = String.format("%."+String.valueOf(3)+"f", 2.123);
```

anf if i=5 then

```
decimals_text = String.format("%."+String.valueOf(5)+"f", 2.123);
```

The issue is that if I use instead of String.valueOf(3) String.valueOf(i) then I get the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rpncalculator, PID: 376
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.rpncalculator/com.example.rpncalculator.MainActivity}:   java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '.'
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '.'
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2781)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2811)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.<init>(Formatter.java:2624)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2557)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2504)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2458)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2770)
    at com.example.rpncalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:134)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

How could this problem be solved?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667864/use-decimalformat-to-get-varying-amount-of-decimal-places

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigDecimal instead

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("2.133");
int roundTo = 2;

bd = bd.setScale(roundTo, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println(bd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you gave a `double` when you supposed to give an `int`.

You should round the `double` to convert to `int` first. You can do it, for example, using `Math.round`.

You can build the format first (using `String.format`) and then use the format to get the string.

```
double i = 3f;
String decimals_format = String.format("%%.%df", Math.round(i)); //for i=3 should give "%.3f"
String decimals_text = String.format(decimals_format, 2.123);
System.out.println(decimals_text);
```